# iOS: How to enable whatsapp web push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, whatsapp

I'm trying to make a app that run whatsapp web. The webview is functioning as it should on whatsapp web client but there is no push notification received. I have registered remote notifications but app does not receive anything. I'm very appreciated if anyone can shed lights over this issue. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: ...production? ...sandbox?

Comment: it's sandbox & production. :D

Comment: When you registered the token in the app, did you get a success? Did that token make it to your server process? When it sent the APN did it get back a success from Apple's server?

Comment: Hi @LouFranco, i did get back device token from APNs. What i really want to know is how app could receive notifications if whatsapp is running on a webview?

Comment: APN only works in one way. App gets a token, App sends token to some kind of server, when you want to push a notification that server sends a request to Apple's APN server with that token.  Every step will report success/failure to diagnose what may be going wrong.

Comment: Hi Lou, that was the part make me confused. I managed to send a voip notification to my app that running whatsapp webview but i could not understand how to pass the notification from phone to iPad (whatsapp notifications)